# How do you format a date for saving with users/saveUser on the front end?

Tags: users, datetime

Currently using a date picker to select a date and submit it on user registration, formatted as **m/d/Y**, have played with various formats but can't one that works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to save this date to? Can you please expand on what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is just the standard front end user registration (based on the example in craft docs) with a couple of custom fields. All is working fine until I add a custom date field to the reg form, working on the assumption it fails on format. So i need to make sure that the input / post formats the date correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Craft stores dates in the database in the following format:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s
```

So submitting the date in this format should work, for example:

```
2014-06-24 23:30:00
```

It should also be possible to split the date and time into individual fields as follows:

```twig
<input type="text" name="fields[customFieldName][date]" value="2014-06-24" />
<input type="text" name="fields[customFieldName][time]" value="23:30:00" />
```

Comment: I've tried this with the split fields, and they do not work - nothing is stored in the date-time field in the back end. If I take the same values and mung them into one input (following your example: `<input type="text" name="fields[customFieldName]" value="2014-06-24 23:30:00" />`) then it does work. Is this a bug I've found?

Comment: Note, the format can vary between locales (apparently). See this Straight Up Craft post for an alternate syntax... https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input